# How do I open the blue gate in Chapter 8 (Core)?

Tags: celeste

In Chapter 8 (Core) of Celeste, shortly after talking with the old woman, you encounter a blue gate with 4 hearts on it.

How do I open the blue gate in Chapter 8?

[image: Blue gate with 4 hearts]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That gate has 4 empty heart images, which means you have to collect 4 Crystal Hearts to open it.

There is a blue Crystal Heart hidden somewhere in each of the previous levels, and another red heart at the end of each B-side level, for a total of 14. If you collect any 4 of those, the gate will open.

See Also: [Celeste Crystal Heart Locations and Solutions Guide](https://www.gameskinny.com/vvye5/celeste-crystal-heart-locations-and-solutions-guide)

Comment: @AlexKChen You could find the ones in the levels instead.

Comment: If you include the Core, there are technically 24 Crystal Hearts. 8 red hearts, 8 blue hearts (B-Side), 8 yellow hearts (C-Side). (See [*Celeste Collectables*](http://www.neoseeker.com/celeste/Celeste_Collectibles))

Comment: I was specifically referring to the crystal hearts that are possible to obtain before entering the Core. Obviously, they can't access the one in the core, or in the core B-side, and without being able to access all of the B-sides, they can't access any of the C-sides. That leaves 14 available crystal hearts.